# I want to create a figure with three bar charts on it

Tags: python, bar-chart

I am trying to create a plot by grouping the data into categories: "Topic", "Person" and "Organisation" similar to this graph:
[image]

How can I do this?

Thank you very much.

This was my coding:

```
figure, axis = plt.subplots(2, 2)

df_per = df_per.sort_values(by=['Frequency'])
y1 = plt.barh(y=df_per.Person, width=df_per.Frequency);
plt.title('Person')

df_org = df_org.sort_values(by=['Frequency'])
y2 = plt.barh(y=df_org.Organization, width=df_org.Frequency);
plt.title('Organization')

df_top = df_loc.sort_values(by=['Frequency'])
y3 = plt.barh(y=df_top.Topic, width=df_top.Frequency);
plt.title('Topic')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the axis that you want to plot on as a two dimensional array:

```
figure, axis = plt.subplots(2, 2)

df_per = df_per.sort_values(by=['Frequency'])
y1 = axis[0,0].barh(y=df_per.Person, width=df_per.Frequency);
plt.title('Person')

df_org = df_org.sort_values(by=['Frequency'])
y2 = axis[0,1].barh(y=df_org.Organization, width=df_org.Frequency);
plt.title('Organization')

df_top = df_loc.sort_values(by=['Frequency'])
y3 = axis[1,0].barh(y=df_top.Topic, width=df_top.Frequency);
plt.title('Topic')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me out. Would you know how to customize my plots the way is shown in the graph?

Comment: Hi. Found the following guide. I hope it helps:
https://towardsai.net/p/data-science/5-tricks-to-improve-bar-graphs-matplotlib